# Error 111 connecting to 127.0.0.1:6379. Connection refused. cPanel (Django)

Tags: django, redis, cpanel, django-redis

I'm using django-redis for caching. Everything works fine on local, but I got an error on production development (using cPanel).

Does anyone know how to use django-redis on the production server?

Comment: Well, is it running? Sometimes you have to manually click the redis-server executable.

Comment: Yeah, I've run the redis-server in local and it works fine on local. But how to run the redis server on production (cPanel)? @nigel239

Comment: Find the executable, and run it. You did install redis, right? Like the actual backend? Instead of the pip module?

Comment: Yes, but I installed it on my local computer. I think we have to install it also on the production right (cPanel in this case)? Because it doesn't make sense if we have to run the redis server all the time on the local computer. @nigel239

Comment: You have to install redis on your production server, yes. https://redis.io/download/

Comment: I don't know how to install Redis on the production server. Can you give me a detailed step-by-step guide or maybe provide some resources that explain that? Because I can't find any guide about how to do that @nigel239